# Trying to get matplotlib to display images as an animation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a class that imports matplotlib when needed and functions as a callback that receives a NumPy array, which should be shown in the next rendered frame. I need to dump this in a window as an animation on the screen. The current code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Renderer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._image = None

    def __call__(self, buffer):
        if not self._image:
            self._image = plt.imshow(buffer, animated=True)
        else:
            self._image.set_data(buffer)
        plt.draw()

renderer = Renderer()
for _ in range(100):
    renderer(
        np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
```

There's some pretty heavy computation doing simulations that are generating each frame, so I don't worry that the frame rate will be too high.

Currently, the code does absolutely nothing, i.e. nothing appears on screen. Does anyone have an idea how to do an animation with the library?

UPDATE: Regarding context, so in my use case an instance of Renderer gets passed down to a layer of code that generates pixels and draws them on the screen by calling the Renderer object. In other words, when something should be drawn is out of my control, I also can't control the frame rate and don't know the time interval between the frames. For this reason what I really need from an API point-of-view is just a way to dump a bunch of pixels on the screen right now.

The FuncAnimation approach has the problem that getting the frames to it would require changing the Renderer callback to put frames on a queue from where the generator generating frames would pull them. FuncAnimation also seems to require me to know the time interval between frames a priori, which I don't know and isn't necessarily constant.

Comment: The code you show, cannot produce any output by itself. See [mcve].

Comment: Alright, was trying to be quick, so someone could answer it during my commute from work. Anyway, I've changed the code to a minimal example, which should draw 100 frames of garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as usual for animations, use interactive mode (`plt.ion()`) or a `FuncAnimation`.

#### Interactive mode (`plt.ion()`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Renderer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._image = None

    def __call__(self, buffer):
        if not self._image:
            self._image = plt.imshow(buffer, animated=True)
        else:
            self._image.set_data(buffer)
        plt.pause(0.01)
        plt.draw()

renderer = Renderer()
plt.ion()
for _ in range(100):
    renderer(
        np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

#### Animation with `FuncAnimaton`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

class Renderer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._image = None

    def __call__(self, buffer):
        if not self._image:
            self._image = plt.imshow(buffer, animated=True)
        else:
            self._image.set_data(buffer)


renderer = Renderer()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def update(i):
    renderer(
        np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, interval=10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ugh... The first one doesn't seem to animate anything. If I put a print statement and a short sleep inside the for loop, it only shows stuff on the screen after the for loop has finished, so there's no actual animation. In other words, what's it trying to accomplish? For the second, since the simulator that I get the frames from control the time, the second approach seems to force me to give matplotlib the time between frames instead of just drawing a frame when I ask it to. This seems really stupid from an API point-of-view, so is this really the only thing that's available?

Comment: Regarding the second approach, so it seems like FuncAnimation would need to use a generator function as the "frames" parameter that pulls the frames from some global queue and yields them while my simulator would be putting frames on that queue. This seems a bit much for just drawing a buffer on the screen. Is there some better Python API than matplotlib that can just draw a buffer of pixels onto the screen with very little code?

Comment: Both codes run fine for me and produce the visually identical output. If you have a problem with any one of them, I can only help if you provide the necessary information about versions, OS, matplotlib backend etc. Concerning `FuncAnimation` you are correct, there is some timing internally used. Now the question would be, why is this a problem? You anyways would not want to draw the animation faster than one can observe it (max framerate for humans is ~40 fps), and you also would not want to draw it slower than needed (because it becomes boring).

Comment: If the calculation of the next buffer element takes longer than some seconds, the approach of showing it with a live animation would anyways require to use a new thread for that, since the GUI would otherwise freeze. If you have a thread providing the buffer you would then sample the current buffer at a constant rate with the GUI.

Comment: The simulation runs at something between 30 and 100fps, so freezing isn't a worry. More than that, I'm looking for minimal code complexity. It seems like the FuncAnimation blocks on the plt.show() call anyway, so the latter approach requires multiple threads no matter what. This is precisely what I wanted to avoid, since it's just a simple simulation for visualizing some scientific data and GUI quality is not a worry.

Comment: Alright, so I wrote a Pipe based two thread solution that has an update function in FuncAnimation that yields frames by doing a blocking read from a pipe. With interval set to 1, it looks like it doesn't wait at all with the drawing once it yields the frame, so it does what I need. Maybe not as simple as I hoped, but it works.

Comment: If code complexety is so important here, maybe you want to spend more thoughts on why the first example does not work for you. You may of course provide any relevant information about system, libraries, the exact process of running the code etc. as to find help here.